# PHPMailer with multiple html tables in mail body

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I am sending mails which contains data of
`Text Content 1`, `HTML Table 1`,`Text Content 2`, `HTML Table 2` and so on..
Note: number of rows and columns in HTML table are dynamic.
My PHPMailer:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer ();
$mail->isSMTP (); 
$mail->Host = '*******.net';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true
$mail->Username = '*****@*****.net'; 
$mail->Password = '*****';
$mail->Port = ****;
$mail->setFrom ( '********', '*********' );
$mail->addAddress ($to , $name ); 
$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
$mail->isHTML ( true );
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$_body = $body;// contains mutiple HTML tables
/*
** $body = "<div>Content1<table align='left'><tr>Table1 content<td></td></tr></table></div><br />";
** $body .= "<div>Content2<table align='left'><tr><td>Table2 content</td></tr></table></div>";
*/
$send = $mail->send ();
$mail->SmtpClose ();
```

**Issue:** I am unable to place my `Content2` right after `Table1`(in a new/next line)
**I want similar to**

```
`content1`
`table1`
`content2`
`table2`
```

**In mail it is sending as**

```
`content1`
`table1` `content2`
`table2`
```

I tried using `<br \>`. Since my number of rows in table are dynamic we could maintain it with using a row counter by appending No. of `<br />`'s for number of rows in `table1`(i.e., If I have 5 rows in table 1, I will append 5 `<br />`'s) I would like to know if there is any better solution

**Solution:**
Previously, I am using `<table align='left'>`, It is indirectly affecting `<table>` as `float:left`. Now my `<br />` tag is working as expected after i remove `align`

Pic1
[image: Pic1]
Pic2
[image: Pic2]

Comment: From your description, using multiple `br` tags makes no sense at all. If the content occurs after the `table` tag, it makes no difference how many `tr`s there are inside it. Nest your tables.

Answer (score 0):

As this is HTML email, just use nested tables. It's ugly and unsemantic, but it's the standard way of coding for email, because of the lack of support for the box model.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ... DESCRIPTION 1 CONTENT ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>... TABLE 1 CONTENT ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ... DESCRIPTION 2 CONTENT ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>... TABLE 2 CONTENT ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Mailchimp has loads of free templates that should give you a headstart on layouts.

Comment: Do we really need nested tables for a simple mail

Comment: @user3616287 From the Mailchimp guide to building HTML emails: _"For finer control of your HTML, try nesting <table> elements when building emails. At its simplest, an email should be at least two tables deep."_ http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/ I've built over 1,000 emails in my career, of varying complexity, and I've never managed to build even a simple email without using at least one nested table. So my answer to your question is "yes, and you may well need even more nesting than that".

Comment: @user3616287 It's a sad turth that, HTML for emails is like programming for the web in 1994.